# clausule like with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, prepared-statement

I'm trying to guess where is a mistake in this method. When I use Navicat to see the result everything is perfect but when  I run my application I have a mistake. It says NullPointerException.

I have written a syso to see if it runs inside the while but nothing and I don't know why, it's anything weird here?.

```
public String[] validarUsuario(String login){

    String [] params = new String [3];

    try {

        System.out.println("Dentro de validarUsuario");
        System.out.println("Login es:"+login);
        String x=login;
        System.out.println("X tiene un valor:"+x);
        this.conexion=conectar();
        SQL="SELECT t1.id_cuenta as id_cuenta,t2.id_usuario as id_usuario,t1.id_tipo_cuenta,t1.n_cuenta as id_tipo_cuenta from usuarios t2 inner join cuentas t1 on t2.id_cuenta=t1.id_cuenta where login LIKE ?";
        System.out.println( "LA CADENA SQL EN 'validarUsuario' ES: " + SQL );
        PreparedStatement pstm6 = this.conexion.prepareStatement(SQL);

        pstm6.setString(1, "%"+x+"%");


        ResultSet rs5 =  pstm6.executeQuery();
        rs5.last(); 
        int numRows = rs5.getRow(); 
        this.rs.beforeFirst();
        System.out.println("NumRows es:"+numRows); 

         while(rs5.next()){
                System.out.println("Dentro del while de esto");
                params[0]=String.valueOf(rs5.getInt("id_cuenta"));
                params[1]=String.valueOf(rs5.getInt("id_usuario"));
                params[2]=String.valueOf(rs5.getInt("id_tipo_cuenta"));

            }

        return params;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return params;

}
```

The stacktrace is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1741)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2898)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
es.uniway.wscloud.WscloudImplSoapBindingStub.validarUsuario(WscloudImplSoapBindingStub.java:640)
es.uniway.action.login.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:188)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
```

Any idea?. Thanks so much.

Comment: Which one is the line 640 in your class: `es.uniway.wscloud.WscloudImplSoapBindingStub.validarUsuario(WscloudImplSoapBindingStub.java:640)`?

Comment: The line 640 from the class you write is this:

Comment: It will be better if you edit your post showing the line instead of posting it in a comment.

Comment: you are calling *beforeFirst()* on *this.rs*, which may be null, not on *rs5*.

Comment: The line 640 from the class you write is this:        java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {login}); which if you see the class from the ws is this pstm6.setString(1, "%"+x+"%");

Comment: guido, thanks, it was because of that

Comment: Your problem is `rs5.last()` because you've created `FORWARD_ONLY` ResultSet.